# Getting the bounding selection rectangle of UIWebView

Tags: javascript, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiwebview

How do we get the on-screen location of a selection in `UIWebView`? That is whenever the user selects some text and the system displays the selection box, I want to know what is the bounding coordinate of the rectangle in screen (or view) units.

The reason for this that I want to display a `UIPopoverController` that has an arrow pointing to the selection rectangle.

I've tried getting the selection via the JavaScript call `window.getSelection()` but it seems that both the resulting `Selection` and `Range` JavaScript objects could not point to the exact screen (or document) relative point (pixel) coordinate since they are not atomic DOM nodes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer here: [How to get coordinates (CGRect) for the selected text in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514648/how-to-get-coordinates-cgrect-for-the-selected-text-in-uiwebview/7725348#7725348)

Basically, you call getBoundingClientRect() on the selected text range.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the physical location of the highlighted range of text from a `UIWebView`.

> The reason for this that I want to
>   display a UIPopoverController that has
>   an arrow pointing to the selection
>   rectangle.

That is not what `UIPopoverController` is for. This is non-standard so it will confuse users and might get you rejected by Apple in the approval process.

Comment: I presume you had your app rejected for this?  Note that this is standard UI in desktop Safari (select a word and press Cmd+Ctrl+D and you'll get a dictionary definition of the selected word -- I want to get the same effect on an iPad).

Comment: I have not had my app rejected for this -- but I would bet money that using it simply as an "arrow pointing to the selection rectangle" would cause rejection. A `UIPopoverController` should contain content related to the control to which it's pointing. As for "desktop Safari" doing something, that has really no bearing on what Apple can impose for iOS.

Comment: but it does point to the related content -- a dictionary points to the word being looked up.

Comment: Well, if your popover has actual content, then that's probably not an issue. Doesn't change the original problem, though, which is getting screen coordinates for a selection range, which you can't get from the underlying class.