# How to get coordinates (CGRect) for the selected text in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, coordinates, cgrect, textselection

I have simple UIWebView with loaded html.
I want to show the PopoverView pointed to the selected text.
I can get the menuFrame of the UIMenuController and use its rect, but the result isn't as accurate at the corners of the screen as I need.
I can calculate the screen size and get menuFrame rect and then I can suppose where the selection may be found, but I want exactly know where is the selected text.
Is it generally possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the javascript function getBoundingClientRect() on the range object of the selected text. 
This is how I do it:

```
function getRectForSelectedText() {
    var selection = window.getSelection(); 
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0); 
    var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect(); 
    return "{{" + rect.left + "," + rect.top + "}, {" + rect.width + "," + rect.height + "}}";
}
```

and in a category on UIWebView, you could use it like such:

```
- (CGRect)rectForSelectedText{
    CGRect selectedTextFrame = CGRectFromString([self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getRectForSelectedText()"]);
    return selectedTextFrame;
}
```

Comment: I have tried but it returns {(0,0),(0,0)} could you help me please

Comment: If we set the scalesPageToFit property of UIWebView then it does not work as expected. Any other solution for same.?

Comment: how to get start and end range of webview selected text