# IOS:Create subMenu using UIMenuItemController inside a UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, submenu, uimenuitem

I would like the behaviour is that:

When I click on my custom UIMenuItem, it would show another list of UIMenuItems to choose.
I have implemented in that way.

```
@implementation CustomUIWebView{
    BOOL clickedShowSubMenu;
    NSArray *mainMenuItems;
    NSArray *subMenuItems;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        UIMenuController *mc = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

        UIMenuItem *testSubMenu = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TestSubMenu" action:@selector(testSubMenu:)];
        mainMenuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:testSubMenu, nil];

        UIMenuItem *subItem1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item1" action:@selector(item1:)];
        UIMenuItem *subItem2 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item2" action:@selector(item2:)];
        subMenuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:subItem1, subItem2, nil];

        [mc setMenuItems:mainMenuItems];

        [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onMenuItemDismissed:) name:UIMenuControllerDidHideMenuNotification object:nil];

        clickedShowSubMenu = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)testSubMenu:(id)sender{
    UIMenuController *mc = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [mc setMenuItems:subMenuItems];
    mc.menuVisible = YES; //from te doc, it say it would keep the menu not dismiss when this function end
    clickedShowSubMenu = YES;
}

- (void)item1:(id)sender{
}

- (void)item2:(id)sender{
}

- (void)onMenuItemDismissed:(id)sender{
    if(clickedShowSubMenu == YES){
        UIMenuController *mc = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [mc setMenuItems:mainMenuItems];
        clickedShowSubMenu = NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender{
    if(action == @selector(testSubMenu:))return YES;
    else if(action == @selector(item1:))return YES;
    else if(action == @selector(item2:))return YES;
    return NO;
}

@end
```

It works when I select long touch some text and click the `Test Sub Menu`, it did appear the "subMenu": `Item1` and `Item2` on the same position that `Test Sub Menu` appear.

However, the problem is the second time and later. I select other text and the `Test Sub Menu` appear correctly, but when I click it ,the `Item1` and `Item2` is showed on the OLD position that it first appear. Their position is never changed. I do not know what cause this.

**EDIT**
Ok. By making use of [How to get coordinates (CGRect) for the selected text in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514648/how-to-get-coordinates-cgrect-for-the-selected-text-in-uiwebview/7725348#7725348) to get the rect boundary of the selection and say `[mc setTargetRect:theRect inView:self];` before `mc.menuVisible = YES;`

It work and the sub menu show approximate same position of the main menu. Is it recommended? There is still little problem that when I highlight a whole paragraph, the main menu is show UNDER the paragraph, however, the sub menu show ABOVE the paragraph.

Comment: I am using [mc setTargetRect:theRect inView:self] by getting theRect using javascript function(selectedText inside UIWebView)..In ios 6.0 it's working..But in iOS 7.0 sub menu frame is not stable.Is your issue got resolved?do u have any suggestions to resolve this?