# How to get the coordinates for the selected text in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have simple `UIWebView` with loaded html file. I want to show the `PopOverController` pointed to the selected text like -

[image].

I want the `coordinates` of selected text from `UIWebView`.
If I set the `scalesPageToFit` property of `UIWebView` to `NO`, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514648/how-to-get-coordinates-cgrect-for-the-selected-text-in-uiwebview/7725348#7725348) link works fine. If I set the `scalesPageToFit` property of `UIWebView` to `YES`, then it fails.

Anyone please help me to sort out my problem.

Comment: Please explain more about your issue.

Comment: @virantporwal I have edited my question for better understanding.

Comment: What is mean by "rect" here?

Comment: OK,then you can try TapUIGestureRecognizer for getting the particulate coordinates.

Comment: @Girish Ohh sorry boss...

Comment: Why is it that you want the coordinates?  I think you can add your own item to the default popup.  (I did it in a project a few years ago)

Comment: @MikeM I want to show the popup from the selected text. I have shown the custom items in popup the issue is related to the positioning of the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the native long press gesture recogniser like this:

```
for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesRecog in yourWebView.gestureRecognizers)
    {
        if([gesRecog isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
        {
            [startTF removeGestureRecognizer:gesRecog];
        }
    }
```

Then assign a custom one:

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *myOwnLongPressRecog = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleWebViewLongpress:)];

        // set numberOfTapsRequired and numberOfTouchesRequired as per your requirement:       

[yourWebView addGestureRecognizer:myOwnLongPressRecog];
```

// Handle Long press like this:

```
 - (void) handleWebViewLongpress: (UIGestureRecognizer *) recog
    {
     int zoomedWidth = [[yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.innerWidth"] intValue];

        CGFloat scale = yourWebView.frame.size.width / zoomedWidth;  // get the scaled value of your web view

        CGPoint zoomedCords = [gesture locationInView:self.webView];

        zoomedCords.x /= scale; // Normal math. Divide by the scale to get the real thing.
        zoomedCords.y /= scale;

NSLog(@"%@", zoomedCords);

            }
```

Comment: I already tried with this but it returns wrong y coordinates due to the scalesPageToFit property.

Comment: change your Y coordinate as scaling happens.

Comment: how can I change the Y-coordinate? User can select any text from the UIWebView.

Comment: You have to get the scaled value. Like when you zoom an image and want to get where the user actually tapped. Check my updated Answer.

Comment: you said before, it was not working. What was the wrong before?? JUst in case I encounter the same problem...

Comment: I didn't set the delegate to the longpress gesture so it does not called its delegate method & not getting the correct output. I set the delegate & it works well. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This must be be accomplished almost completely within JavaScript and then have the result passed back into Objective C. If you have control of the content you are showing, you can add this function into a `<script>` tag. Otherwise you will need to inject it as described in [this post](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview).

```
function rectsForSelection() {
    var i = 0, j = 0;
    var allSelections = window.getSelection();
    var result = []; // An empty array right now
    // Generally, there is only one selection, but the spec allows multiple
    for (i=0; i < allSelections.rangeCount; i++) {
        var aRange = allSelections.getRangeAt(i);
        var rects = aRange.getClientRects();
        for (j=0; j<rects.length; j++) {
            result.push(rects[j]);
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

Then from your Objective C code, you use do something like this:

```
NSString *rectsString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"rectsForSelection();"];
NSData *rectsData = [rectsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *rects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rectsData
                                                 options:0
                                                   error:NULL]; //Do Your Own Error Checking
```

I'll add that this will get coordinates that are valid within your `webView.scrollView`, not your `webView`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried that?

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(getCoordinates:)];
//  [longPress setMinimumPressDuration:1];
[yourWebView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];


- (void)getCoordinates:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {

CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"Tap at %1.0f, %1.0f", location.x, location.y);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView actually renders the HTML into UIViews, specifically it will probably render the selectable text into UITextView, so what you have to do is try to tap into the right view's delegate methods.

Here's a hack that should work:

1. Wait until the web view is fully loaded.
2. Traverse over the UIWebView's subviews as described by Ole Begemann [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746478/how-can-i-loop-through-all-subviews-of-a-uiview-and-their-subviews-and-their-su).
3. Once you reach a UITextView tap into its delegate method, you could do something similar to a delegate chain to obtain this - [here's a post about it](http://www.xs-labs.com/en/archives/articles/cocoa-delegate-chain)
4. Implement the `UITextViewDelegate` method `textViewDidChangeSelection:` to get the selectedRange and interact with it.

** An alternative to step 3 and 4 is to use KVO to listen to changes in the textView's selectedRange.